# Print 3 variables from macro together with selected Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I select rows to print from table with 7 columns. I use the `PrintOut` method to print them out.

Is there an elegant way to add 3 variables values at the top of the paper before the selected rows?

I can set some cells with the values of these variables and then on next rows paste the selected rows from table and then print the newly created table. But it seems too complicated.

Here is my macro:

```
Sub FindMyNubmer()
    Dim a As Range, b As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim eurStart As Long
    Dim eurEnd As Long
    Dim usdStart As Long
    Dim usdEnd As Long
    Dim gbpStart As Long
    Dim gbpEnd As Long
    Set a = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65000")

    For Each b In a.Rows
        If ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "EUR" Or ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "EUR-" Then
            eurStart = eurStart + ActiveSheet.Range("G" & b.Row)
        End If
        If ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "USD" Or ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "USD-" Then
            usdStart = usdStart + ActiveSheet.Range("G" & b.Row)
        End If
        If ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "GBP" Or ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "GBP-" Then
            gbpStart = gbpStart + ActiveSheet.Range("G" & b.Row)
        End If
        If b.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("H4").Value Then
            If firstRow = "0" Then
                firstRow = b.Row
            End If
            lastRow = b.Row
            If ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "EUR" Or ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "EUR-" Then
                eurEnd = eurEnd + ActiveSheet.Range("G" & b.Row)
            End If
            If ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "USD" Or ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "USD-" Then
                usdEnd = usdEnd + ActiveSheet.Range("G" & b.Row)
            End If
            If ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "GBP" Or ActiveSheet.Range("D" & b.Row) = "GBP-" Then
                gbpEnd = gbpEnd + ActiveSheet.Range("G" & b.Row)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    eurEnd = eurStart - eurEnd
    usdEnd = usdStart - usdEnd
    gbpEnd = gbpStart - gbpEnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & firstRow & ":G" & lastRow).Select
    MsgBox eurStart & " - " & eurEnd
    MsgBox usdStart & " - " & usdEnd
    MsgBox gbpStart & " - " & gbpEnd
End Sub
```

If I change the .Select method to PrintOut it will print the cells in Range as expected.

I want to put eur / usd / gbp Start/End variables on top before printing.

Since the table has 7 columns I would like to print something like this before the table cells.

```
EUR       eurStart var.          eurEnd var.
USD       ...                    ...
GBP       ...                    ...
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you just want to print Start/End values before the range prints. Do they all need to be on the same row ? Have you tried using a "header" with the variables, or perhaps `With Selection` `.print` etc ?

Comment: no i haven't don't know how this header and With Selection works, will check it

Comment: Can you give me a screen shot (or just type some) of the data in the cells and columns. I'm working on a script for print headers, but need some info in the sheet to test. I've got some random numbers in A1 thru G5, what's in H4 ?

Comment: in H4 is something like .   `1/1/2017`

Answer (score 1):

here is a rewrite of your code. it is not meant as an answer to your question.

you have some logic errors. your code still checks for USD and GBP even after EUR matches.

```
Sub FindMyNubmer()

    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long

    Dim eurStart As Long, eurEnd As Long
    Dim usdStart As Long, usdEnd As Long
    Dim gbpStart As Long, gbpEnd As Long

    Dim ddd As String
    Dim ggg As Long

    Dim b As Range
    For Each b In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65000")

        ddd = b.Columns("D")
        ggg = b.Columns("G")

        Select Case ddd
            Case "EUR", "EUR-":    eurStart = eurStart + ggg
            Case "USD", "USD-":    usdStart = usdStart + ggg
            Case "GBP", "GBP-":    gbpStart = gbpStart + ggg
        End Select

        If b.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("H4").Value Then

            If firstRow = 0 Then firstRow = b.Row

            lastRow = b.Row

            Select Case ddd
                Case "EUR", "EUR-":    eurEnd = eurEnd + ggg
                Case "USD", "USD-":    usdEnd = usdEnd + ggg
                Case "GBP", "GBP-":    gbpEnd = gbpEnd + ggg
            End Select
        End If
    Next

    eurEnd = eurStart - eurEnd
    usdEnd = usdStart - usdEnd
    gbpEnd = gbpStart - gbpEnd

    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & firstRow & ":G" & lastRow).Select

    MsgBox "eur" & vbTab & eurStart & " - " & eurEnd & vbCrLf _
         & "usd" & vbTab & usdStart & " - " & usdEnd & vbCrLf _
         & "gbp" & vbTab & gbpStart & " - " & gbpEnd

End Sub
```

Comment: nice thanks, i know i had performance issues could replace either with Switch like you did, or with else If logic. Thanks your code works good. Still need to place these eur / usd / gbp Start End variables on the print page before the selected cells.

Tried with `Range(firstRange, secondRange).printPreview` and it seems to work. but the point is that Before this i had to put the variable values into cells and then select them too which is not a very good approach imo

Comment: actually im wrong its not only a performance issue becouse it changes the eurStart / End even if it is usd or gbp.

Answer (score 0):

This is crude but it works. Incorporate this into your script. Adjust accordingly

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.LeftHeader = _
"EUR               " & eurStartvar & "               " & eurEndvar & Chr(10) & "USD               " & usdStartvar & "               " & usdEndvar & Chr(10) & "GBP                " & gbpStartvar & "               " & gbpEdnvar & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

End With
```